# Specify docx layout in markdown

Tags: format, markdown, knitr, pandoc

I am using r markdown to produce word documents of the output of my code.

I was wondering if there is a way that i can specify that the pages are `landscape` with `narrow margins` (approx 1.75) with everything formatted from the `center` of the page with a specific design layout and if there is a way to specify the position of the images on each page e.g. pg4 image 1 left center, image 2 top right, image 3 bottom right.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid the answer is negative. Although I am not an R Markdown expert, I believe using markdown is the wrong approach to create documents with such detailed formatting requirements. To quote the original [markdown:](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/)

> The overriding design goal for Markdown’s formatting syntax is to make
>   it as readable as possible. The idea is that a Markdown-formatted
>   document should be publishable as-is, as plain text, without looking
>   like it’s been marked up with tags or formatting instructions. While
>   Markdown’s syntax has been influenced by several existing text-to-HTML
>   filters, the single biggest source of inspiration for Markdown’s
>   syntax is the format of plain text email.

You could embed HTML in markdown for more control over the styling, but even then you will find it hard to control most of the page layout aspects you are interested in.

Moreover, HTML is actually a **markup** language. in other words, you would move far away from that original idea of **markdown**.

What I could imagine that might help you is to use a two step process. First create the HTML Output with R Markdown. Then use an other tool to convert the HTML to PDF or so and define your layout settings in this second step.